# what is the diffence between WAS and IIS?

Tags: iis, was

Is WAS distinct from IIS?
How is WAS better than IIS?

Comment: Did you mean Windows Activation Services or Websphere application Server?

Comment: Was is the past tense of Iis.

Comment: WAS is WebSphere Application Server to most people.
I guess for MS shops WAS stands for Windows Process Activation Service.
So, in 1994 or so we had CGI which could fork() processes.
Then, we got web servers with shared libraries.
Now, MS has put process activation into IIS.  Party like it's 1994!
Caveat lector: simultaneous incoming connection count is limited by OS edition.  Well played, MS.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

WAS is a new feature of IIS, that allows all the features of the Windows Communication Framework stack, like non-HTTP channels and other stuff. IIS is the web server that hosts the services that are activated via WAS.

Check out [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/september/iis-7-0-extend-your-wcf-services-beyond-http-with-was) for details.

Answer (score 22):

In case you mean Windows Activation Service: 
WAS - is the new process activation mechanism that ships with IIS 7.0. WAS builds on the existing IIS 6.0 but is more powerful because it provides support for other protocols besides HTTP, such as TCP and Named Pipes.

The WAS hosting is the real new feature because it provides a concept that extends the ASP.NET HTTP hosting concept (ASMX Web Services). As a standalone Windows component, WAS is completely separated from the IIS hosting environment and provides a protocol-agnostic activation mechanism, so you aren’t limited only to HTTP. WAS allows you to choose the most appropriate protocol for your needs:

- for HTTP, data transfer relies on the ASP.NET HTTP
- for protocols such as TCP and Named Pipes, WAS leverages the extensibility points of ASP.NET for transferring data.

Comment: Wikipedia could do with some of the insights from above - its article is sorely lacking in detail: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Activation_Services

Answer (score 1):

Windows Process Activation Service, also referred to as WPAS, is a new component in IIS 7.0 that manages application pool configuration and worker processes instead of the WWW process. This enables the same configuration for both HTTP and non-HTTP sites to be used.

http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Windows-Process-Activation-Service-in-IIS-70